# How do I map different arrays based on state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, state

I currently have a toggle button. When false, it should hide the red cards (late jobs) in it's column. When true, all jobs should be shown. However it is not working. The state changes, but no re render happens.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [showLateJobs, setShowLateJobs] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("default");
  const multipleUsersArray = [...otherUser, ...AllJobs];

  let toOrderArray =
    user === "default"
      ? AllJobs.filter((job) => job.category === "to_order")
      : multipleUsersArray.filter((job) => job.category === "to_order");

  let toOrderArrayNoLate =
    user === "default"
      ? AllJobs.filter((job) => job.category === "to_order" && job.late != true)
      : multipleUsersArray.filter(
          (job) => job.category === "to_order" && job.late != true
        );

  const [toOrderState, setToOrderState] = useState(
    showLateJobs ? toOrderArray : toOrderArrayNoLate
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Toggle
        defaultChecked={true}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (!e.target.checked) {
            setShowLateJobs(false);
            console.log("toggled");
          } else {
            setShowLateJobs(true);
          }
        }}
      />

      <Column>
        {toOrderState.map((job, index) => (
          <JobCard
            job_number={job.jobNumber}
            time={job.time}
            cardHeight={layout === "extended" ? "150px" : "50px"}
            layout={layout}
            backgroundColor={job.late && "#D64045"}
            displayLateIcon={job.late && "block"}
          />
        ))}
      </Column>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: where is your `setShowLateJobs`

Comment: @sillyknight02 Added the rest of the state hooks now, (they were originally in the code)

Comment: i am not 100% sure if you setShowLateJobs , and that will fire toOrderState re-init or not. so try to add an useEffect to handle this like `useEffect(()=>{if(showLateJobs ) setToOrderState(toOrderArray ) else setToOrderState(toOrderArrayNoLate) },[showLateJobs])`

Comment: @sillyknight02 This works in toggling the late jobs now. However, when the user state is changed to anything other than default, the other array (multipleUsers) isn't selected until you toggle again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're setting your computed values into state as initial values. Since you're never calling `setToOrderState(...)`, the state value never changes.

If you'd like to derive new state from existing state, you can use a [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

```js
// Define these outside your component
// so they're not re-initialised every render
const DEFAULT_USER = "default";
const CATEGORY_FILTER = "to_order";

const multipleUsersArray = [...otherUser, ...AllJobs];

const filterPredicate =
  (includeLate) =>
  ({ category, late }) =>
    category === CATEGORY_FILTER && (includeLate || !late);
```

```js
// And these inside your component
const [showLateJobs, setShowLateJobs] = useState(true);
const [user, setUser] = useState(DEFAULT_USER);

const toOrderState = useMemo(
  () =>
    (user === DEFAULT_USER ? AllJobs : multipleUsersArray).filter(
      filterPredicate(showLateJobs)
    ),
  [user, showLateJobs] // hook dependencies
);
```